# Highlighting two child controls simultaneously

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a windows form with two child controls. I need to highlight both the controls at the same time using c#. Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "highlight"? What types of controls? What visual effect do you wish to present to the user?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "highlight"? Are you referring to both controls having focus? Also, what kind of controls are the child controls?

Comment: Do you mean you need two of them to have focus at the same time?

Comment: Yeah, bu highlight I mean to focus both  the controls. I am working with TreeView control in c#. I need to highlight more than one TreeNodes at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to highlights nodes in the TreeView control

```
// condition when to highlight
if (treeNode.Text.StartsWith("Important"))
{
   treeNode.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The MS TreeView control does not support multi-select, so if that is what you have to use, you would have to use a method like what Peter suggest. The Infragistics UltraWinTree control has multi-select capabilities.